# Multiple passes with awk and execution order

Tags: awk

Two part question:

Part One:
First I have a sequence AATTCCGG  which I want to change to TAAGGCC.  I used gsub to change A to T, C to G, G to C and T to A.  Unfortunetly awk executes these orders sequentially, so I ended up with  AAACCCC.  I got around this by using upper and lower case, then converting back to upper case values, but I would like to do this in a single step if possible.

example:

```
echo AATTCCGG | awk '{gsub("A","T",$1);gsub("T","A",$1);gsub("C","G",$1);gsub("G","C",$1);print $0}'
```

OUTPUT:
AAAACCCC

Part Two:
Is there a way to get awk to run to the end of a file for one set of instructions before starting a second set?  I tried some of the following, but with no success

for the data set

```
1 A
2 B
3 C
4 D
5 E
```

I am using the following pipe to get the data I want (Just an example)

```
awk '{if ($1%2==0)print $1,"E";else print $0}' test | awk '{if ($1%2==0 && $2=="E") print $0}'
```

I am using a pipe to rerun the program, however I have found that it is quicker if I don't have to rerun the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a method I have found for the first part of the question using awk.  It uses an array and a for loop.

```
cat sub.awk
awk '
        BEGIN{d["G"]="C";d["C"]="G";d["T"]="A";d["A"]="T";FS="";OFS=""}
        {for(i=1;i<(NF+1);i++)
                {if($i in d)
                        $i=d[$i]}
                                }
        {print}'

Input/Output:
ATCG
TAGC
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be efficiently solved with `tr`:

```
$ echo AATTCCGG | tr ATCG TAGC
```

Regarding part two (this should be a different question, really): no, it is not possible with `awk`, pipe is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

for part two, try this command:

```
awk '{if ($1%2==0)print $1,"E"}' test
```